# When switching ant desing tabs it shows previous table instead of choosen table react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, tabs, antd

```
    <Drawer
       width={"80%"}
       placement="right"
       closable={true}
       title={assetName[1]}
       onClose={self.onClose}
       visible={self.state.visible}
    >
  <Spin spinning={self.state.detailLoading}>
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" type="card" onChange={self.callback} >  
            <TabPane
              tab={
                <span>
                  {trans('dataTracking.productivity')}
                </span>
              }
              key="1"
            >  
             <Productivity
                 detailKey={self.state.detailKey}
                /> 
        </TabPane>
       <TabPane
              tab={
                <span>
                  {trans('dataTracking.working')}
                </span>
              }
              key="2"
            >  
                <Working
                 detailKey={self.state.detailKey}
                 detailLoading={self.state.detailLoading} 
                />          
       </TabPane>
        </Tabs>
       </Spin>
       </Drawer>
     )}
```

**I'm using tables in Ant design tabs. But when changing the tabs, the previous table appears instead of the table I opened.There are different tables in the transitions between tabs. But when I want to go back to the table I opened at first, the data of the previous table comes. **

Comment: Hi 

Is it possible for your to show your code and have a reproduction example ?

Comment: Can you show your code so, we will exact idea of what are you doing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added part of my code